# Is ECMAScript case sensitive?

Tags: javascript

I understand that JavaScript (the language that implements the spec) [is case sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types). For example, variable names:

```
let myVar = 1
let MyVar = 2 // different :)
```

I haven't been able to find anything in [the spec itself](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) that indicates that this is a requirement, so I'm not sure if that was just a design decision independent of the spec.

Comment: The answer is **yes**.  Almost all common programming languages are case sensitive.

Comment: The spec doesn't say that it's case-sensitive because it doesn't need to. If identifiers consisting of different characters were supposed to be considered equivalent, it would say so.

Comment: I think @Barmar is correct, but I think for completeness sake it would make sense to specify what comparison method source code characters used. However, it is highly implied that they are compared as unicode code points in some portions of the spec. But I do think this is something that seems so obvious that it wasn't ever made explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found something that specifies this. [Names and Keywords](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-names-and-keywords) says:

> Two *IdentifierNames* that are canonically equivalent according to the Unicode standard are *not* equal unless, after replacement of each *UnicodeEscapeSequence*, they are represented by the exact same sequence of code points.

Since uppercase and lowercase letters have different code points, identifiers with different case are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is case sensitive but generally JavaScript developers follow **camel case** convention.

Comment: Your link relates to DHTML concepts more than pure javascript concepts :).